# Python finance: Create a DataFrame (columns = many tickers; rows = date) made up of total asset values

Tags: python, dataframe, finance, cycle

i'd like to know the python code to get something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRrcj.png)

where on the rows we have the dates and on the columns the various tickers (for example all the sp500 companies) and the values ​​are their total assets.

For only one company the code is this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AScKE.png)

but I can't do it for hundreds of companies. Can you help me? I thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi Gianmarco, please add the code into your question instead of adding it as an image. Makes it easier for people to help you with your question :)

Answer (score 0):

I created a code to get the income statements of several stocks on Yahoo Finance. Many stocks can be included in a list or imported as a CSV file. The code is then looped through to retrieve and combine them. After that, transpose and modify the column names. For the next question, please post the code as text instead of an image. This has the advantage that you will get a faster answer.

```
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

symbol = ["AAPL", "TSLA", "AMZN", "NKE", "GOOG", "KO"]
tickers = yf.Tickers(" ".join(symbol))
all_assets = pd.DataFrame(columns=['symbol','Total Assets'])

for i,ticker in enumerate(tickers.tickers):
    try:
        assets= tickers.tickers[i].balance_sheet.T["Total Assets"].to_frame()
        assets['symbol'] = symbol[i]
        all_assets = pd.concat([all_assets, assets], axis=0)
    except:
        pass

all_assets.head(10)

symbol  Total Assets
2020-09-26  AAPL    3.238880e+11
2019-09-28  AAPL    3.385160e+11
2018-09-29  AAPL    3.657250e+11
2017-09-30  AAPL    3.753190e+11
2020-12-31  TSLA    5.214800e+10
2019-12-31  TSLA    3.430900e+10
2018-12-31  TSLA    2.974000e+10
2017-12-31  TSLA    2.865537e+10
2020-12-31  AMZN    3.211950e+11
2019-12-31  AMZN    2.252480e+11

all_assets.pivot(columns='symbol').head(5)
    Total Assets
symbol      AAPL    AMZN    GOOG    KO      NKE             TSLA
2017-05-31  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     2.325900e+10    NaN
2017-09-30  3.753190e+11    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2017-12-31  NaN     1.313100e+11    1.972950e+11    8.789600e+10    NaN     2.865537e+10
2018-05-31  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     2.253600e+10    NaN
2018-09-29  3.657250e+11    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer and give it 1+, thanks!

Comment: thanks for the reply, unfortunately it doesn't work. There's an error in "Total Asset": KeyError: 'Total Assets'.

Comment: Not all stocks have total asset data, so error handling may be required.

Comment: Another library, 'yahoo_fin', could be used to add each stock to the data frame in a loop process.

Comment: Were you able to handle the error? The code has been modified to include error handling. Also, the acquisition format is converted from the data frame to the horizontal format at the end. We have made it so that it can handle both wide and long formats.

Comment: I m a beginner on python, but I copied your code and after "all_assets.head(10)" it creates an empty dataframe with "symbol" and "Total Assets" on the columns. Maybe I m doing something error, I don t know.

Comment: with the yahoo_fin library you can not do it? Anyway thanks!